# Is there any alternative to QVector in PyQt4 or PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt4

I need to work with Vector in PyQt4, but unfortunately, PyQt4 not include it:

```
rects = QVector(region.rects())
data = QVector();
for rect in rects.count():
  r = QRect(rect)
  data << r.x() << r.y() << r.width() << r.height()
```

Comment: Can't you just use a list?

Comment: Heike, thanks by your comment, i will try, but i never use a list before...

Comment: Heike, you mean like this: List(region.rects())?

Comment: No, more like `list(region.rects())` (all lower case). BTW, I assume that `region` is a `QRegion` object in which case `region.rects()` returns a list already, so there is no need to recast it.